# Regular Expression RegEx - Multiline / Concatenate / Trim

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text such:

```
abc
_def
ghi_
_efg_
```

!!! Important: '**_**' means in my example above a **space** or not **visible char**

I want a code which gives me the following result:

```
abc;def
ghi;efg
```

which means:

1. remove for each line leading and trailing spaces
2. concatenate all lines with a semicolon ;
3. create a package of 2 records (in my real case it is 250)

I have the following code so far:

```
var dataList = document.getElementById("dataList").value;  // read text area
var dataList_arr_packaged = dataList.match(/(?=[\s\S])(?:.*\n?){1,2}/g);  // create a package of 2 records 

for (i =0; i<dataList_arr_packaged.length; i++) {
        var currValues = dataList_arr_packaged[i].replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ";");    // concatenate within 1 package all records with a ;         
}
```

But my code above gives me as result

```
abc;_def
ghi_;_efg_
```

(again '_' means space):

How can I split as I described above, *but also delete the spaces* (=trim)?

Many Thanks,
Kalem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this with a `split()`/`reduce()` combination.

```js
let data = `abc
 def
ghi 
 efg `

let output = data.split("\n").reduce((b, a, i) => {
  if (i % 2 === 0) b.push(a.trim());
  else b[b.length - 1] += ";" + a.trim();
  return b
}, [])

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace(/\s*(.+?)\s*/, '$1')` for space trimming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern to first match 2 lines, where the first line starts with a non whitespace char.

Then match the second line starting with optional chars other than a non whitespace char and at least a single non whitespace char.

```
^\S.*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*\S.*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\S.*` Match a non whitespace char and the rest of the line
- `\r?\n` Match a newline
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match optional leading chars other than a whitespace
- `\S.*` Match a single non whitespace char and 0+ times any char except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mAA0z6/1)

Then in the replacement, first trim the match to get rid of the leading and trailing spaces, and replace all whitespace chars with a `;`

```js
const regex = /^\S.*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*\S.*/gm;
let dataList = `abc
 def
ghi
 efg `
const result = dataList.replace(regex, m => m.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ';'));
console.log(result);
```